# Infinite Loop in ARM Raspberry Pi Assembly Code

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi, arm

I'm working on an ARM Raspberry Pi assembly code where I intend to go over the numbers from 1 to a user-input value, and print the first number greater than that input value.
So if input = 5 then output = 6. This is just a project for learning the basics.
However, I encountered an issue with an infinite loop in my code. I initially reloaded the values inside the check_loop_range but still faced the problem.

```
check_loop_range:                       @ Checks if we should continue with loop_range
        ldr r0, =number                 @ r0 <- &number
        ldr r0, [r0]                    @ r0 <- *r0
        ldr r1, =current_number         @ r1 <- &current_number
        ldr r1, [r1]                    @ r1 <- *r1

        cmp r0, r1                      @ compare r0 and r1
        blt end                         @ if r0 <= r1 branch to end

loop_range:                             @ This loop goes trough all numbers from 1 to 'number'
        add r2, r1, #1                  @ Add one to r1
        ldr r1, =current_number         @ r1 <- &current_number
        str r2, [r1]                    @ *r1 <- r2
        b   check_loop_range            @ Continue loop
```

Eventually I solved the problem by reloading the values inside loop_range as well.

```
check_loop_range:                       @ Checks if we should continue with loop_range
        ldr r0, =number                 @ r0 <- &number
        ldr r0, [r0]                    @ r0 <- *r0
        ldr r1, =current_number         @ r1 <- &current_number
        ldr r1, [r1]                    @ r1 <- *r1

        cmp r0, r1                      @ compare r0 and r1
        blt end                         @ if r0 <= r1 branch to end

loop_range:                             @ This loop goes trough all numbers from 1 to 'number'
        ldr r0, =number                 @ r0 <- &number
        ldr r0, [r0]                    @ r0 <- *r0
        ldr r1, =current_number         @ r1 <- &number
        ldr r1, [r1]                    @ r1 <- *r1

        add r2, r1, #1                  @ Add one to r1
        ldr r1, =current_number         @ r1 <- &current_number
        str r2, [r1]                    @ *r1 <- r2
        b   check_loop_range            @ Continue loop
```

But **I don't understand why this works, and why the previous code was causing an infinite loop**.
Here is the entire (working) code.

```
/* The data section hold the variables we will use */
.data

.align 4
number:                 .word 0         @ Input give by the user

.align 4
scan_pattern:           .asciz "%d"     @ Pattern to pass as argument to scanf

.align 4
print_pattern:          .asciz "%d\n"   @ Pattern to pass as argument to printf

.align 4
number_abundant:        .word 0         @ The number of abundant numbers from 1 to 'number'

.align 4
number_deficient:       .word 0         @ The number of deficient numbers from 1 to 'number'

.align 4
number_perfect:         .word 0         @ The number of perfect numbers from 1 to 'number'

.align 4
current_number:         .word 1         @ We start evaluating numbers from 1, up to 'number'

.align 4
return:                 .word 0         @ We will store lr here on function calls

/* Code Section */

.text

.global main
main:
        ldr r1, =return                 @ r1 <- &return
        str lr, [r1]                    @ *r1 <- lr             ; save return address

        ldr r0, =scan_pattern           @ r0 <- &scan_pattern   ; first argument to scanf
        ldr r1, =number                 @ r1 <- &number         ; second argument to scanf
        bl  scanf                       @ call scanf

check_loop_range:                       @ Checks if we should continue with loop_range
        ldr r0, =number                 @ r0 <- &number
        ldr r0, [r0]                    @ r0 <- *r0
        ldr r1, =current_number         @ r1 <- &current_number
        ldr r1, [r1]                    @ r1 <- *r1

        cmp r0, r1                      @ compare r0 and r1
        blt end                         @ if r0 <= r1 branch to end

loop_range:                             @ This loop goes trough all numbers from 1 to 'number'
        ldr r0, =number                 @ r0 <- &number
        ldr r0, [r0]                    @ r0 <- *r0
        ldr r1, =current_number         @ r1 <- &number
        ldr r1, [r1]                    @ r1 <- *r1

        add r2, r1, #1                  @ Add one to r1
        ldr r1, =current_number         @ r1 <- &current_number
        str r2, [r1]                    @ *r1 <- r2
        b   check_loop_range            @ Continue loop

end:
        ldr r0, =print_pattern
        ldr r1, =current_number
        ldr r1, [r1]
        bl  printf

        ldr lr, =return                 @ lr <- &return
        ldr lr, [lr]                    @ lr <- *lr
        bx  lr                          @ exit

/* External */
.global printf
.global scanf
```

Makefile

```
all: Pro04

Pro04: Pro04.o
        gcc -o $@ $+

Pro04.o: Pro04.s
        as -g -mfpu=vfpv2 -o $@ $<

clean:
        rm -vf Pro04 *.o
```

Other data that may be relevant (?)

```bash
Architecture:          armv7l
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
Model name:            ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
CPU max MHz:           1200.0000
CPU min MHz:           600.0000
```

```bash
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

Comment: Works fine here. Verify you actually use the code shown.

Comment: My apologies, the section with the full code presents the full working code. The error presents itself when removing lines:
        ldr r0, =number                  @ r0 <- &number
        ldr r0, [r0]                           @ r0 <- *r0
        ldr r1, =current_number     @ r1 <- &number
        ldr r1, [r1]                           @ r1 <- *r1
From loop_range

Comment: I did remove that, yes. Still works.